# Nginx logs: client closed connection while SSL handshaking

Tags: nginx, centos, ssl, openssl

CentOS 7.2
Nginx 1.13.0
PHP 7.1.4

My error logs has a lot of the below lines

```
2017/05/16 06:32:05 [info] 18838#18838: *10061 client closed connection while SSL handshaking, client: 120.188.122.190, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

What exactly is the meaning of this log?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The client connecting to nginx server didn't like something during the SSL handshake and closed the connection. Enabling more verbose logging can reveal more details why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue while attempting to enable mTLS and if like me, you've defined `ssl_client_certificate` make sure you certificate ends in `*.crt` not `*.pem`